# How to configure a cache proxy to cache everything regardless of cache headers?

Tags: networking, proxy, cache

I am wondering if there was a cache proxy available that would cache every single request after initial visit to a HTML web page visit avoiding subsequent call's to the home server.

The system will have to ensure future requests of any kind do not attempt to call to a live server so a web page could be reloaded in complete offline mode.

Thanks.

Comment: Just in case: note that this will severely mess up the responses of web sites to which users need to log in.

Comment: Understood, It would be the selected system would be per-user based, in a container or something.